# how to access the last record of a table of db and to the fields of the last record in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to access a specific field of the db keeping in mind that I want to consult the last record of the database. I do this in laravel, for the moment I have the following:

```
$buscar=DB::table('ciclo')            //In this way I look for the last record
    ->select(DB::raw('max(idCiclo) as idCiclo'))
    ->get();
```

then he tried to make a query in order to find the id of the last I record he searched before

```
$ultimo= DB::table('ciclo')
    ->select('idCiclo', 'fechaFinal')
    ->where('idCiclo', '=', $buscar)
    ->first();
```

When executing it tells me the following error

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

what's going on? I'd appreciate your help...

Comment: please post your complete code of your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**
 it is because `$buscar` is object of `stdClass` which has `idCiclo` attribute. (It is possible `$buscar` has null when in db no records)

```
$ultimo= DB::table('ciclo')
    ->select('idCiclo', 'fechaFinal')
    ->where('idCiclo', '=', $buscar->idCiclo)
    ->first();
```

You can do that more short ways

```
$maxIdCiclo = DB::table('ciclo')->max('idCiclo'); // return max idCiclo or null 
$ultimo= DB::table('ciclo')
        ->select('idCiclo', 'fechaFinal')
        ->where('idCiclo', '=', $maxIdCiclo)
        ->first();
```

Comment: I tried and I throw this new error::  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @JuanAntonio are you try it??

Comment: I already tried. and it  found the value I needed, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can even try this

```
$ultimo= DB::table('ciclo')
    ->select('idCiclo', 'fechaFinal')
    ->orderBy('idCiclo', 'DESC')
    ->take(1)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

First in both queries you have errors both in logic and in results. As for the first you can give completely erroneous results, not necessarily the id with maximum value corresponds to the last record. In your second query the error is thatyour variable `$buscar`  is a collection type and not a string, that's why the error.

**I suggest you do like this:**

```
$ultimo = DB::table('ciclo')
            ->select('idCiclo','fechaFinal')
            ->orderBy('idCiclo', 'desc')
            ->limit(1)
            ->get();
```